# NPM install not working for Node V 16.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am having trouble finding a solution to this. I am trying npm install for a project but I get a very large error. I have pasted just a small part of it below. Any helping in fixing this issue would be really appreciated.

```
npm ERR!   V8_DEPRECATED("Use GetBackingStore. See http://crbug.com/v8/9908.")
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! /Users/kali/.node-gyp/16.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:415:35: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define V8_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
npm ERR!                                   ^
npm ERR! 1 warning and 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/kali/web_projects/webproj1/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/kali/web_projects/webproj1/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kali/web_projects/webproj1/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "node-sass --watch css/style.scss css/style.css",
    "build": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./js/* ",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run watch\" \"npm run build\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "gsap": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I am running Node version 16.0.0 and NPM version 7.10.0. I am on macOS Big Sur

Comment: Remove `node-sass` (you can see the log being about this package not being compilable), because it's been [deprecated for quite a while now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) and doesn't support anything after Node 15, install [just plain `sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), without the `node-` prefix, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Worked! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Worked for me too, but just had to update a couple of my @import paths after changing from node-sass to sass.

Comment: Worked man !! for node 16

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, worked for me too. had node 16 then I updated node-sass to ^6.0.1